# Fazer um relacionamento com dados já criados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel, relacionamento

Estou fazendo um sistema de cadastro escolar com o laravel. Ele possui, atualmente, duas tabelas no banco de dados: a lista de Turmas e a lista de Professores.
Na hora de cadastrar uma turma nova, quero poder inserir um professor já cadastrado, mas sempre que tento isso, o laravel tenta criar um professor novo.

Migration das Turmas:

```
Schema::create('turmas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('turma');
            $table->string('nivel');
            $table->string('ano');
            $table->string('turno');
            $table->integer('vagas');
            $table->bigInteger('professor')->unsigned()
                ->references('id')->on('professores')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Model da Turma

```
protected $table = 'turmas';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'turma',
        'nivel',
        'ano',
        'turno',
        'vagas',
        'professor'
    ];

    public function professor() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Professor', 'id');
    }
```

Controller da Turma

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $class = new Turma;
        $class->turma = $request->input('turma');
        $class->nivel = $request->input('nivel');
        $class->ano = $request->input('ano');
        $class->turno = $request->input('turno');
        $class->vagas = $request->input('vagas');
        $class->professor()->professor = $request->input('professor');
        $class->save();
    }
```

Migration dos Professores

```
 Schema::create('professores', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('nome');
            $table->string('sobrenome');
            $table->string('sexo');
            $table->string('data_Nascimento');
            $table->string('tel')->nullable();
            $table->string('tel2')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Model do Professor

```
protected $table = 'professores';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nome',
        'sobrenome',
        'sexo',
        'data_Nascimento',
        'tel',
        'tel2',
        'email'
    ];
    
    public function turma()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Turma');
    }
```

Controller do Professor

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $prof = new Professor();
        $prof->nome = $request->input('nome');
        $prof->sobrenome = $request->input('sobrenome');
        $prof->sexo = $request->input('sexo');
        $prof->data_Nascimento = $request->input('data_Nascimento');
        $prof->tel = $request->input('tel');
        $prof->tel2 = $request->input('tel2');
        $prof->email = $request->input('email');
        $prof->save();
        
        return redirect()->route('listaProfessor');
    }
```

Formulario de Cadastro

```
<div class="container col-8" align="center">
            <input type="hidden" id="id" class="form-control">

                {{--- Formulario Turma ---}}
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="turma" class="control-label">Turma: *</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="turma" name="turma" placeholder="Nome da Turma"
                            value="{{ isset($cras->turma) ? $cras->turma : old('turma') }}">
                    </div>
                </div>

                {{--- Formulário Nível ---}}

                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="sobrenome" class="control-label">Nível: *</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <select name="nivel" id="nivel" class="form-control">
                            <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione uma Opção</option>
                            <option value="Fundamental">Fundamental</option>
                            <option value="Medio">Médio</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {{--- Formulário Ano ---}}

                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="ano" class="control-label">Ano: *</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <select name="ano" id="ano" class="form-control">
                            <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione um Ano</option>
                            <option data-ano="Fundamental" value="1° ano">1º Ano</option>
                            <option data-ano="Fundamental" value="2° ano">2º Ano</option>
                            <option data-ano="Fundamental" value="3° ano">3º Ano</option>
                            <option data-ano="Fundamental" value="4° ano">4º Ano</option>
                            <option data-ano="Fundamental" value="5° ano">5º Ano</option>
                            <option data-ano="Fundamental" value="6° ano">6º Ano</option>
                            <option data-ano="Fundamental" value="7° ano">7º Ano</option>
                            <option data-ano="Fundamental" value="8° ano">8º Ano</option>
                            <option data-ano="Fundamental" value="9° ano">9º Ano</option>
                            <option data-ano="Medio" value="1° ano">1º Ano</option>
                            <option data-ano="Medio" value="2° ano">2º Ano</option>
                            <option data-ano="Medio" value="3° ano">3º Ano</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                {{--- Formulário Turno ---}}

                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="data_Nascimento" class="control-label">Turno: *</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <select name="turno" id="turno" class="form-control">
                            <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione um turno</option>
                            <option value="Manhã">Manhã</option>
                            <option value="Tarde">Tarde</option>
                            <option value="Noite">Noite</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

            {{--- Formulario Vagas ---}}
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="vagas" class="control-label">Número de Vagas: *</label>
                    <div class="input-group ">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control phone_with_ddd" name="vagas" id="vagas"
                            value="{{ isset($cras->vagas) ? $cras->vagas : old('vagas') }}"
                            placeholder="ex: 10" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                {{--- Formulario Professor ---}}

                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="tel2" class="control-label">Professor:</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <select name="professor" id="professor" class="form-control">
                            <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione um Professor</option>
                            @foreach ($professor as $prof)
                                <option value="{{ $prof->id }}">{{ $prof->nome }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{{ url()->previous() }}">Cancelar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No controller da turma, nesta linha:

```
$class->professor()->professor = $request->input('professor');
```

Você está tentando adicionar um valor inteiro a um campo que não existe em Professor, quando usa `$class->professor()` o "retorno" seria um model relacionando. Basta associar o if que está recebendo no request diretamente ao campos professor do modelo turma

```
$class->professor = $request->input('professor');
```